# Multiplying the Entire Sheet by 2

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Test()

    Dim rngData As Range

    Set rngData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.ActiveCell
    rngData = Evaluate(rngData.Address & "*2")
End Sub
```

I am trying to multiple the entire sheet by 2, yet I am getting an error. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks
Hayk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub MultiplyByTwo()
    Dim r As Range, rng As Range

    On Error Resume Next
        Set rng = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    For Each r In rng
        r.Value = 2 * r.Value
    Next r
End Sub
```

It multiplies all numeric constant cells in the worksheet by **2**.  It will ignore:

1. empty cells
2. text cells
3. formula cells

Comment: Since this runs over an entire spreadsheet, would turning calculation to manual, and screen updating false at the start help performance in any measurable way?

Answer (score 2):

The below will multiply the `ActiveCell` by two.  Note that this does not multiply the entire sheet!

```
Sub Test()
    Dim rngData As Range
    Set rngData = ActiveCell
    rngData = Evaluate(rngData * 2)
End Sub
```

If you truly want to multiply all values in the worksheet by 2, I would look in to looping through a range.

Comment: @dwirony - `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ActiveCell` throws an error. Is that because `ActiveCell` implicitly already includes `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")` (assuming `Sheet1` is the activesheet?)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly less conventional way to approach this, but you could use the `Paste Special... > Multiply` feature.  E.g., for this example, I placed a `2` in cell `A17`, and applied the multiplier to my `A1:F15` range.  Here's what that looks like programmatically:

```
Sub MultiplyAll()
    Range("A17").Select 'select the multiplier from cell A17
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy 'capture the multiplier "2" onto the clipboard
    Range("A1:F15").Select 'select the range that will be multiplied
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlMultiply, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

This might not be a great approach for your use case, but consider that you might not even need a macro if you just need to paste your multiplier onto a range manually.

Comment: It's best to [Avoid using `.Select`/`.Activate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/)